# Reloading a page leads me to the root path in angular cli

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I have configured the routing for my app. but whenever a page is refreshed, even if the current route is not the `root or default` route, the app redirects me to the `root`.
this is how i configured the routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'  },
  { path: 'donors', component: DonorComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
    { path: 'seeDonors', component: SeeDonorComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'newDonor', component: NewDonorComponent }
  ] },
  { path: 'bloodStock', component: BloodStockComponent },
  { path: 'donationCenter', component: DonationCenterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'branch', component: BranchComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and the AuthGuard checks if the used is logged in or not here is the code

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    const isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    if (!isAuth) {
      // this.router.navigate(['/']);
    } else {
    }
    return isAuth;
  }
}
```

help me how to resolve this...if my question is not clear, i will explain in more detail.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why do you need to reload the page? Angular applications are usually single page applications that are able to render and reload data without having to reload the page.

Comment: [during development] when i save a file in the project, angular automatically complies it and reloads the page...so after compilation i am always at `http://localhost:4200/`, but i want to stay where i was...that is why

Comment: for example if i was on `http://localhost:4200/donors` route, after reloading it redirects me to `http://localhost:4200/`

Comment: the this.authService.getIsAuth(); returns true?

Comment: when a user is logged in it returns `true` otherwise `false`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the logic of the guard. I think maybe the problem come from their

I have an example here

```js
    async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
            const user = await this.myservice.getUserAuthState();
            if (!user) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

You will need to return return true or false and not redirect user in the guard. The guard only you have a permission to go to that component or module if you dont the guard will redirect you to main url

Hope it will help.